# C++11 style SFINAE and function visibility on template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, argument-dependent-lookup

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with sfinae, or just something thats relevant for any templated function. I am attempting to use sfinae to enable/disable a member function based on existence of corresponding free function, which in turn is enabled/disabled based on existance of member function in another type, all using method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154394/1554020):

```
struct S;

template <typename T>
inline auto f(S& s, T const& t)
   -> decltype(t.f(s), void())
{
   t.f(s);
}

struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f(T const& t)
        -> decltype(f(*this, t), void())
    {
        f(*this, t); // <------------------------------------------- HERE
    }
};

struct pass
{
    void f(S&) const
    {
        //...
    }
};

struct fail
{
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.f(pass()); // should compile fine
    //s.f(fail()); // should fail to compile due to absence of f from S
    return 0;
}
```

however gcc 4.7.1 gives me this on the line marked by arrow:

> error: no matching function for call to 'S::f(S&, const pass&)'
>   
>  note: candidate is:
>   
>  note: template decltype ((f((* this), t), void())) S::f(const T&)
>   
>  note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   
>  note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided

which apparently means that global `f` above is not considered for overload resolution.

Why is that and what do I do to make it do so?

Also why are there no errors two lines above that, where `f` used in decltype in similar fashion?

**UPDATE**

As @n.m. said, member functions completely shadow free functions, even when their signatures are different, so here is a workaround that doesn't break ADL for `f` (unlike the full name qualification suggested by @n.m. ). Make free function (`f_dispatcher`) somewhere nobody will look (`detail`), and fully qualify its name inside `S::f`. In that function call free `f` and let ADL take care of it from there onwards, like so:

```
struct S;

template <typename T>
inline auto f(S& s, T const& t)
    -> decltype(t.f(s), void())
{
    t.f(s);
}

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    inline auto f_dispatcher(S& s, T const& t)
        -> decltype(f(s, t), void())
    {
        f(s, t);
    }
}

struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f(T const& t)
        -> decltype(detail::f_dispatcher(*this, t), void())
    {
        detail::f_dispatcher(*this, t);
    }
};

struct pass
{
    void f(S&) const
    {
        //...
    }
};

struct fail
{
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.f(pass()); // compiles fine
    //s.f(fail()); // fails to compile due to absence of f from S
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a using-declaration inside `S::f` as well?

Comment: @dyp, I can, but that won't make it visible in trailing return type.

Comment: The trailing-return-type is part of the declaration, so name lookup inside it won't find the declaration it's part of.

Comment: @dyp, you are right, it works as intended.

Comment: (Note that it has some downsides: it's not very reliable as introducing overloads or member functions of the same name inside base classes will break it. C++1y's return type deduction can be used instead.)

Comment: @dyp return type deduction doesnt allow sfinae.

Comment: Oops, right, you wanted to use it for SFINAE. Well then it might part of the yet unsolved ADL problem. Similar problems occur for `noexcept`-specifiers. One suggestion was to allow a using-declaration inside `decltype` etc., but IIRC it wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SFINAE or templates or C++11 or ADL.

A member *shadows* all non-members with the same name, regardless of type. If you have a member named `f`, you cannot refer to any non-member named `f`, unless you use a qualified name (e.g. `::f`).

Just use `::f(*this, t);`.

Comment: Whoa, apparently I never before had to use a free functionfrom inside member one with the same name. You are indeed correct. But i can not just use qualified name here, i need adl to work on it.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that will not have effect on the use inside `decltype`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas it seems there is no need for that, it's visible there anyway.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas i believe you can use _using declaration_ at class scope only on members of base classes and nothing else.

Comment: @yurikilochek You are right, I am taking the liberty of removing all the absurd comments :)

Comment: @yurikilochek "_I never before had to use a free functionfrom inside member one with the same name._" Not even `swap`?