# Can't use helper function with same name as member function

Tags: c++

This code compiles (Using GCC / C++11):

```
void doStuff_HELPER(int a) { /**/ }

class SomeClass{

public:
    void doStuff() {doStuff_HELPER( 10);}

};
```

This doesn't:

```
void doStuff(int a) { /**/ }

class SomeClass{

public:
    void doStuff() {doStuff( 10);}

};
```

It doesn't say it's ambiguous or it can't be overloaded or anything it just says: "no matching function SomeClass::doStuff(int)", "candidate: void SomeClass::doStuff()". Is this the correct behavior? What does the standard say about this?

(Also, what is the best practice for such helper functions? Should they be put into a separate namespace maybe?)

Comment: The compiler is correct, the function call is resolved using [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) ([see here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696029/why-class-member-functions-shadow-free-functions-with-same-name)). Both the free function and class method are reachable and valid lookups.

Comment: `::doStuff(10);` is not ambiguous. Neither is `this->doStuff(10);` - if you name things in different scopes the same you have to help the compiler figure out which function you mean. The easy solution is to just not use the same name. The alternative is to explicitly tell the compiler which one you want to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [Scope Resolution Operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-operator-in-c/) to resolve this.  Using `::doStuff(10)` instead of `doStuff(10)` tells the compiler to look in the **global** namespace to resolve the name collision.

Answer (score 3):

Call it explicitly specifying scope: `::doStuff(10);`