# Find free function that has been shadowed by a member function

Tags: c++, name-lookup, shadowing

How can I find a free function that has been shadowed by a member function in a class.

```cpp
namespace some_namespace
{
    struct the_type{};
    void function(the_type);
}

namespace other_namespace
{
    template<class T>
    class my_wrapper
    {
    public:
        void function()
        { function(m_value); }
    private:
        T m_value;
    }
};
```

Here, I do not know in what namespace to look, so I cannot use any qualification. The implementation is expected to be found by ADL. Is the only way to escape the class by adding a wrapper function outside the class with a different name?

[Why class member functions shadow free functions with same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696029/why-class-member-functions-shadow-free-functions-with-same-name)

Answers why it is like it is, but does not suggest what the canonical workaround is.

Comment: How do you not know what namespace the free function is in? That really does not make sense to me.

Comment: Is it even "shadowed" in this case? You can't use function from another namespace without specifying namespace here.

Comment: @ChrisMM *"How do you not know what namespace the free function is in?"* -- It looks to me like the reason is that `T` is a template parameter, the template does not know in what namespace `T` is defined, and the free function taking a `T` parameter is defined in the same namespace as `T`. That being said, I agree that the question's text should be made clearer in this regard.

Comment: @KIIV *"You can't use function from another namespace without specifying namespace here."* -- You can if it has a different name, thanks to [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL). *(If you add a main function, such as `int main() {
other_namespace::my_wrapper<some_namespace::the_type> object;
object.function();
}` then compilation fails. However, if you change the function name in `some_namespace` and make the same change to the function invoked inside `my_wrapper::function()` then compilation succeeds.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason ADL fails<sup>†</sup> is because unqualified lookup finds `my_wrapper::function`. So we shadow that by bringing a dummy free function into scope.

```cpp
namespace some_namespace
{
    struct the_type{};
    void function(the_type);
}

namespace other_namespace
{
    struct dummy {};
    void function(dummy);

    template<class T>
    class my_wrapper
    {
    public:
        void function()
        {
            using other_namespace::function;
            function(m_value);
        }
    private:
        T m_value;
    };
}
```

<sub>† Actually, no ADL is performed.</sub>

Comment: Interesting: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bdvvqrE8n. I guess this is preferred over using a wrapper that forwards all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the shadowing, a function with another name is needed.

```cpp
namespace some_namespace
{
   struct the_type {};
   void  function( the_type ) {}
}

namespace other_namespace
{
   template<class T> auto  relay_for_function( T&& t ) {
      return  function( std::forward<T>(t) );
   }

   template<class T>
   class my_wrapper
   {
   public:
      void  function() {
         relay_for_function( m_value );
      }
   private:
      T  m_value;
   };
};
```

Comment: I already knew about this trick, but it feels a little bit clunky.

Comment: @user877329 • What in particular is the clunky?  The thunk relay function is inlined and should optimize out to nothing.  The amount of boilerplate is annoying.  Using the same method name as the freestanding function name from the other namespace could have been avoided by renaming one of them.