# sfinae on member function defined outside of class body

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, decltype

Kind of a continuation from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694970/c11-style-sfinae-and-function-visibility-on-template-instantiation). What I've got is a bunch of functions that form a sfinae depencency chain like so (let "A -> B" notation mean that existence of A depends on existence of B):

```
S::f_base -> S::f -> ns::f_ -> f -> T::f
```

where T is the template argument. It's implemented like [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/9780ef0aa9b85e6464dbf1538ab4ae25):

```
#include <utility>

struct S;

template <typename T>
auto f(S& s, T const& t) -> decltype(t.f(s), void())
{
    t.f(s);
}

namespace ns
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f_(S& s, T const& t) -> decltype(f(s, t), void())
    {
        f(s, t);
    }
} 

struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f(T const& t) -> decltype(ns::f_(std::declval<S&>(), t), void())
    {
        ns::f_(*this, t);
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto f_base(T const* t_ptr) -> decltype(f(*t_ptr), void())
    {
        f(*t_ptr);
    }
};

struct pass
{
   void f(S&) const
   {
   }
};

struct fail
{

};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.f(pass()); // compiles
    //s.f(fail()); // doesn't compile
    return 0;
}
```

and works as intended. The problem arises when I attempt to move definitions of `S::f` and `S::f_base` outside the class body, like [so](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f54caec1993057b576c04d0608b22cdf):

```
#include <utility>

struct S;

template <typename T>
auto f(S& s, T const& t) -> decltype(t.f(s), void())
{
    t.f(s);
}

namespace ns
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f_(S& s, T const& t) -> decltype(f(s, t), void())
    {
        f(s, t);
    }
} 

struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f(T const& t) -> decltype(ns::f_(std::declval<S&>(), t), void());

    template <typename T>
    auto f_base(T const* t_ptr) -> decltype(f(*t_ptr), void());
};

template <typename T>
auto S::f(T const& t) -> decltype(ns::f_(std::declval<S&>(), t), void())
{
    ns::f_(*this, t);
}

template <typename T>
auto S::f_base(T const* t_ptr) -> decltype(f(*t_ptr), void()) // <---- HERE ---
{
    f(*t_ptr);
}

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

On the line marked by arrow `GCC 4.7.1` expresses it's dissatisfaction:

> error: prototype for 'decltype ((((S*)0)->S::f((* t_ptr)), void())) S::f_base(const T*)' does not match any in class 'S'
>   
>  error: candidate is: template decltype ((((S*)this)->S::f((* t_ptr)), void())) S::f_base(const T*)

I tried to explicitly specify which `f` I'm using in `f_base` by prepending it (in both declaration and definition) with `std::declval<S&>().`, but the error persists.

I know I can modify the dependency graph like so:

```
S::f_base ->
          -> ns::f_ -> f -> T::f
S::f      ->
```

to make `S::f_base` depend on `ns::f_` along with `S::f`, but is there a way to do this with the first dependency graph?

Comment: Obvious question: Why do you *want* to move the definition outside of the class body?

Comment: @Xeo to separate interface from implementation, at least visually, as these function are actually way bigger than simplified one-liners here.

Comment: The second code works with Clang r161057 with GCC 4.6.3's libstdc++ on Windows.

Comment: Seems to be a bug with GCC, as Clang compiles fine (according to [rubenvb](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4755825#4755825)). Wouldn't have thought anything else, since the declarations are completely the same.

Comment: compiles with VS2012 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC 4.X is not the best for meta programing

I have manage to make it compile in 4.7.3 ([live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6UbfUzOsskrKKgqI)) :

```
#include <utility>

struct S;

template <typename T>
auto f(S& s, T const& t) -> decltype(t.f(s), void())
{
    t.f(s);
}

namespace ns
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f_(S& s, T const& t) -> decltype(f(s, t), void())
    {
        f(s, t);
    }
} 

// some std::void_t like but GCC4.x compatible
template<class T>
struct void_t
{
   using type = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,T>::value >::type;
};

struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    auto f(T const& t) -> decltype(ns::f_(std::declval<S&>(), t), void());

    template <typename T>
    auto f_base(T const* t_ptr) ->  typename void_t< decltype (::f(*std::declval<T const*>()))>::type ;
};


template <typename T>
auto S::f(T const& t) -> decltype(ns::f_(std::declval<S&>(), t), void())
{
    ns::f_(*this, t);
}

// ::f is needed, fail if just 'f'
template <typename T>
auto S::f_base(T const* t_ptr) ->  typename void_t< decltype (::f(*std::declval<T const*>()))>::type
{
    f(*t_ptr);
}
int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:**

In GCC4.X I have seen some weird stuff like :

```
template<class T>
struct void_t
{
   using type = void;
};
```

Where GCC replace `void_t<decltype(expr)>::type` by `void` even if `expr` is not valid. That why I use this implementation of `void_t`.