# How to define member of sfinae class outside of class declaration?

Tags: c++11, templates, sfinae

After reading questions such as [sfinae on member function defined outside of class body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758559/sfinae-on-member-function-defined-outside-of-class-body) (which isn't the same question), and other, I still don't get the good way to define the body of a member function outside the class declaration when using a SFINAE approach to enable the class only with arithmetic types.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,T>::type>
class foo
{
public:
    void bar();
};

template <typename T>
void foo<T>::bar ()
{
}
```

In this example, I get the error :

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class foo<T>'
void foo<T>::bar ()
^
error: declaration of 'class foo<T>'
class foo
^
```

Whereas if I declare it like so :

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T,typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,T>::type>
class foo
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
    }
};
```

It functions without any trouble whatsoever.

I am using mingw-w64 (w64 3.3) to compile this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo` has two template parameters, even if one of them is unnamed, defaulted and used for SFINAE. Hence:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void foo<T, U>::bar ()
{
}
```

Comment: in this case, how come if you declare a function taking two foo as const ref parameters, you don't need to specify the second typename ?

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume Such as `void baz(foo<int> const &)` ? That's because it is simply using (instantiating) `foo`. Defining `foo`, on the other hand, requires you to be explicit about what part of which `foo`s you're on about. Your syntax *could* have meant "use the default parameter", but in your case you'd be defining a single member function of a partial specialization (`foo<T, void>`), [which is not permitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335762/partial-specialization-of-member-function).